Connected to WiFi but no access to internet
I was able to connect to the Internet until Sunday. I couldn't connect to the Internet on Monday. Nothing has changed on my PC. The only thing I did was sudo apt-get update but it didn't download too much. As far as I can remember, it only downloaded a few kb of data.
In the house, all the phones are able to connect to the internet via WiFi, except my laptop. When I select the WiFi, it looks connected at first, but then a question mark (?) appears on the WiFi icon. Additionally, when I share my mobile internet with my laptop, everything works fine.
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01)

$ ifconfig
br-1db02a26bdd0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.31.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.31.255.255
        ether 02:42:92:72:37:b2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-35b3c8def3c9: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.30.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.30.255.255
        ether 02:42:64:e8:d0:1e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-3864e73fa63c: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.49.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.49.255
        inet6 fe80::42:59ff:fe9d:2268  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:59:9d:22:68  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 267887  bytes 17232669 (17.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 468759  bytes 934153764 (934.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-3a165a5c993a: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.25.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.25.255.255
        ether 02:42:98:38:3c:21  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-46e81cf5fb5e: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.240.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.255.255
        ether 02:42:eb:a5:f2:33  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-4ca8610e3d72: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.15.255
        ether 02:42:7c:d6:5d:d0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-4d363be4b599: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        ether 02:42:1e:c6:9f:e1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-4e168a0cdf31: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.27.255.255
        ether 02:42:b8:a4:bf:08  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-604867f1852d: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.22.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.22.255.255
        ether 02:42:d0:56:d6:12  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-8166f1f24274: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.24.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.24.255.255
        ether 02:42:94:2e:79:5f  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-9346c9dd9a25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.26.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.26.255.255
        ether 02:42:08:08:d5:8a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-a28feae6b83c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.21.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.21.255.255
        ether 02:42:45:e1:6a:58  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-a593dce43362: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:5d:2f:e4:36  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-c77e5c8b1ce6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.16.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        ether 02:42:fe:10:d9:e5  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-c8d5ce7ce6c1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.29.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.29.255.255
        ether 02:42:f1:7a:30:29  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-dafd9fc1c73f: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.23.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.23.255.255
        ether 02:42:43:bc:cd:78  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-f2e659a6d01a: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
        ether 02:42:7f:f1:f8:28  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-fd59d8ed402b: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.28.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.28.255.255
        ether 02:42:8d:fa:69:88  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:c5ff:fe3d:29e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:c5:3d:29:e6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4  bytes 300 (300.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9  bytes 1143 (1.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp47s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d8:bb:c1:b1:1d:c1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 263  bytes 26552 (26.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 317  bytes 29647 (29.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 38038  bytes 5493492 (5.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38038  bytes 5493492 (5.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.10.250  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.10.10.249
        inet6 fe80::a0ce:d0ea:f4a6:fe9b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 61  bytes 7612 (7.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 218  bytes 27560 (27.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth0dc7448: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::18aa:8ff:fe8e:523e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1a:aa:08:8e:52:3e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 267887  bytes 20983087 (20.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 468794  bytes 934158782 (934.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.10.2  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 172.20.10.15
        inet6 fe80::29e5:ff56:dd82:cbc5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c4:bd:e5:23:9c:9a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 747554  bytes 1042650489 (1.0 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 337029  bytes 35702664 (35.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


